# Problems installing Python 3 with --enable-shared

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, debian, mod-wsgi

### Problem

I'm trying to install Python 3 with the --enable-shared option. Installation "succeeds" but the resulting Python is not runnable. Trying to run Python after installation gives the following error:

```
$ /opt/python3/bin/python3.5
/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

#### Background

The OS is Debian (squeeze), and has a previous installation of Python 2.6, which is necessary to retain because other code relies on it, and Apache 2.2. Ultimately what I'm trying to do is set up Django to run on Apache, meaning I'm trying to install mod_wsgi (or mod_wsgi-express), which requires shared libraries. I have already tried to install mod_wsgi *without* using `--enable-shared` in the Python installation, and have gotten... well, the same thing, but this time from the mod_wsgi installer (and from `pip install mod_wsgi`, which I also tried): `/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

### Trace

Starting from an installation as described in **Background** above, here is the minimum list of commands I've executed that produce the error above (with verbosity removed).

```
user@server:~$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tgz
user@server:~$ tar -zxvf Python-3.5.1.tgz
user@server:~$ cd Python-3.5.1
user@server:~/Python-3.5.1$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/python3 --enable-shared
user@server:~/Python-3.5.1$ make && sudo make install
(... appears to install correctly)

user@server:~/Python-3.5.1$ /opt/python3/bin/python3.5
/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried this with `LD_RUN_PATH` set as described in the solution to this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157184/strange-python-compilation-results-with-enable-shared-flag), with the same results:

```
user@server:~/Python-3.5.1$ sudo make distclean
user@server:~/Python-3.5.1$ ./configure --prefix=/opt/python3 --enable-shared
user@server:~/Python-3.5.1$ LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make
user@server:~/Python-3.5.1$ sudo make install
user@server:~/Python-3.5.1$ /opt/python3/bin/python3.5
/opt/python3/bin/python3.5: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried this with Python 3.4, with the same results. I have not tried this with Python 2, because I do not want future development to be limited to Python 2.7 (therefore even a successful installation would not satisfy my requirements). I'm also assuming the attempt would not provide any new or useful information.

Comment: Why not install it from the repos? apt-get install python3

Comment: I'm trying to make sure it uses shared libraries. Is there a way to do that with apt-get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've repeated your steps on CentOS7 and get something similar:

```
$ /tmp/py3/bin/python3
/tmp/py3/bin/python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

If you look at the linking of python, it isn't providing a full path to the library:

```
$ ldd /tmp/py3/bin/python3
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff47ba5000)
    libpython3.5m.so.1.0 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdfaa32e000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fdfaa12a000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fdfa9f27000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdfa9c24000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdfa9862000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055e85eac5000)
```

For some reason, the Python build process isn't adding `-rpath` to the link line, which would "add a directory to the runtime library search path."

If you explicitly set your library path, it will work:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/tmp/py3/lib/ /tmp/py3/bin/python3
Python 3.5.1 (default, Jun 10 2016, 14:54:59) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

So now it becomes a question as to whether you want to:

- set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` globally on your system
- Edit `/etc/ld.so.conf` (or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/*`)
- Use `chrpath` to change the embedded path
- `export LD_RUN_PATH={prefix}/lib` before you run `configure` and `make`
   *(Where `{prefix}` is what you passed to `--prefix`.  You used the wrong path.)*

Comment: As for the last option, you can also pass loader flags to `./configure`. For example: `./configure --prefix=/opt/python3 --enable-shared LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /opt/python3"`.

Comment: Thanks @rrauenza! The part I was missing was that `LD_RUN_PATH` is related to `--prefix`, not an absolute/standard location.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the mod_wsgi documentation, set `LD_RUN_PATH` at the time of installing mod_wsgi.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/installation-issues.html?highlight=ld_run_path#unable-to-find-python-shared-library

Comment: Thanks Graham. Maybe I shouldn't have tagged this mod-wsgi though because the problem is happening in the Python installation step, before I even get to installing mod-wsgi. I'll keep this in mind when I do, though.

Comment: Go read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/installing-custom-python-version-into.html Ignore that it says Docker, all still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the installation of python to be portable, i.e. to --prefix at /install but then distribute a bundle that the user can put anywhere, the RPATH needs to be relative. I was able to do that by setting this variable:

LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN/../lib' -z origin -Wl,--disable-new-dtags"

before running the build. Escaping $ORIGIN can be funky because of makefiles and shells but this seems to work.