# Python3.5 installation fails: cannot open libpython3.5m.so.1.0

Tags: python-3.5

I'm trying to install Python 3.5.2 on CentOS 7.  The build appears to succeed, but executing **python3** elicits

```
python3: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757314/problems-installing-python-3-with-enable-shared) as the only link that appeared to help.  **ldd** does show the file as missing, and it does not seem to exist anywhere, although **/usr/lib/libpython3.5m.so** exists.

By any chance, is **/usr/lib/libpython3.5m.so** the correct file?  I have no problem making a link, but I don't want to shoot myself in the foot if it's wrong.  I also wonder whether there are related layers of yak fur waiting for me.  Perhaps I need to **make clean** and rebuild with other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much along the same lines as the quoted question, I still need to repair LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  The global solution is at least a workaround:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/
```

The problem was mostly in locating the wayward file.

Answer (score -1):

You should make it by  `./configure --enable-shared`
then
`make && make install`

after that,
`vim /etc/ld.so.conf.d/python3.conf` && and add a new line 
`/usr/local/lib`
try  `/sbin/ldconfig`
hope it works !