# Python 3.5 installation from source missing libpython3.5m.so.1.0

Tags: python, python-3.5

I'm trying to install python 3.5 on my computer running Ubuntu 14.04.1 for use with pytorch. apt-get does not appear to have a standard distribution of 3.5 yet, so I thought I could install it from source.

To install, I ran

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.3/Python-3.5.3.tgz
tar xzvf Python-3.5.3.tgz
cd Python-3.5.3
 ./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-shared
make
sudo make install
```

I use the --enable-shared flag because it is required by pytorch according to [this thread](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/997).

When I try to open python3.5, I get the following error

> python3.5: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.5m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I've tried the solution from [Python3.5 installation fails: cannot open libpython3.5m.so.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38256696/python3-5-installation-fails-cannot-open-libpython3-5m-so-1-0), exporting a LD_LIBRARY variable, but it doesn't work for me.

I originally tried to build without the --enable-shared flag which worked better. I could open python3.5, but it threw the same error when I ran `import torch`.

Comment: If you're just looking for a means to an end you could check out the Anaconda distro, https://www.continuum.io/downloads