# Possible python3.8 build problem on Centos 7

Tags: python, centos, pyinstaller

I have built python3.8 on a virgin installation of Centos 7.7 via:

```
CXX="/usr/bin/g++"
export CXX

./configure LDFLAGS="-static -static-libgcc" CPPFLAGS="-static" \
            --enable-optimizations \
            --prefix=/opt/python38 \
            --enable-shared     \
            --enable-static     \
            --with-system-expat \
            --with-system-ffi   \
            --with-ensurepip=yes

snaptime=`date +%Y%m%d.%H%M`
/usr/bin/make -j `nproc` 2>&1 | /usr/bin/tee log.${snaptime}

echo "remember to 'make altinstall' to avoid overwriting your system python"
```

Next, I attempt to build a standalone executable via "pyinstaller hello.py"

I receive the following output/errors:

```
$ pyinstaller hello.py
25 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
25 INFO: Python: 3.8.0
53 INFO: Platform: Linux-3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.17
53 INFO: wrote /home/usr/testpy1/hello.spec
54 INFO: UPX is not available.
55 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/usr/testpy1', '/home/usr/testpy1']
55 INFO: checking Analysis
55 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
55 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
56 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
57 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2331 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
2342 INFO: Caching module hooks...
2345 INFO: Analyzing /home/usr/testpy1/hello.py
2348 INFO: Loading module hooks...
2348 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
2378 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
2379 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
2504 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
2506 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
2507 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
2511 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
2795 INFO: Looking for eggs
2796 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyinstaller", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "/home/usr/testpy1/hello.spec", line 6, in <module>
    a = Analysis(['hello.py'],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 243, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 575, in assemble
    self._check_python_library(self.binaries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 681, in _check_python_library
    raise IOError(msg)
OSError: Python library not found: libpython3.8.so.1.0, libpython3.8m.so.1.0, libpython3.8m.so, libpython3.8mu.so.1.0
This would mean your Python installation doesn't come with proper library files.
This usually happens by missing development package, or unsuitable build parameters of Python installation.

* On Debian/Ubuntu, you would need to install Python development packages
  * apt-get install python3-dev
  * apt-get install python-dev
* If you're building Python by yourself, please rebuild your Python with `--enable-shared` (or, `--enable-framework` on Darwin)
```

When I check my build directory, sure enough, the specified files (libpython3.8.so.1.0, libpython3.8m.so.1.0, libpython3.8m.so, libpython3.8mu.so.1.0) do not exist in my build directory, nor in my /usr/lib and /usr/lib64 directories.

Also, from the root directory, I have run "cd '/' && find . | grep -i libpython3.8" and received one line of output ->

```
/home/usr/python3.8/Python-3.8.0/libpython3.8.a
```

Because I have both --enable-shared and --enable-static on the ./configure command-line, I expect both .a and .so files to be generated with the build and altinstall, but that is obviously not happening.

I am also aware that the problem may be from 'pyinstaller' - perhaps it is not yet working with versions of python greater than 3.5?

Comments? Suggestions? Questions?

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757314/problems-installing-python-3-with-enable-shared) out.