# Altinstall of Python 2.7.13 on RHEL7 just launches system version

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, rhel, rhel7

I'm doing an altinstall of Python 2.7.13 on RHEL7 which has 2.7.5 installed. Here's how I'm building from source:

```
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --enable-shared
$ make && sudo make altinstall
```

However, even when I tried to access this altinstall directly, I'm getting the system Python, rather than the altinstall. I've put SELinux into permissive mode and get the same result.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.5
$ getenforce
Permissive
```

and when I enter the interpreter

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.7
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  2 2016, 04:20:16)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I'm at a loss here. From everything I've been reading this should work. The only thing I can think of is that since they're both 2.7.X there's some sort of conflict, but I thought that was the reason for altinstalls in the first place.

Comment: You could maybe altinstall in another place ?

Comment: I've tried that as well with no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're running into the same problem as in this thread: [Strange Python compilation results with “--enable-shared” flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157184/strange-python-compilation-results-with-enable-shared-flag).

To fix it, you need to use:

```
LD_RUN_PATH=/usr/local/lib make && sudo make altinstall
```

(So that the generated binary looks for the correct shared Python library.)

---

As a sidenote, I think you'd be much better served by Red Hat Software Collections when you need to have different Python versions on one system. Check out [About RHSCL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Software_Collections/2/html-single/2.3_Release_Notes/index.html#sect-RHSCL-About).

Comment: That was it - thank you for your time. I tried many different variations and none of them were working.